# SharePoint filtering list with multiple values of the same field

Tags: url, sharepoint

> "Display the items in the list that either belongs to the category
>   Health or Entertainment."

I have a sample list: `http://www.example.com/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx`

And if I am to filter the list items to look for Categories with the value "Entertainment", the URL will look like this:

`http://www.example.com/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?View={ViewId}&FilterField=Categories&FilterValue=Entertainment`

Suppose I'd like to filter by the list items with the Categories "Entertainment" OR "Health". Unfortunately, this URL would not work as I can only filter with 1 value for the same field at a time:

`http://www.example.com/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?View={ViewId}&FilterField1=Categories&FilterValue1=Entertainment&FilterField2=Categories&FilterValue2=Health`

**What is the URL for filtering with multiple values of the same field ("OR" condition) in a SharePoint list?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the name/value pair of `FilterName` and `FilterMultiValue` in your query string to achieve an OR filter.

For example, to filter a standard Tasks list view in a SharePoint Team Site to return all items that are "Completed" or "Deferred", your URL would look like:

```
http://www.example.com/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?View={ViewId}&
FilterName=Status&FilterMultiValue=Completed;Deferred
```

In your use case, the new URL would be:

```
http://www.example.com/Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx?View={ViewId}&
FilterName=Categories&FilterMultiValue=Entertainment;Health
```

*UPDATE*:
Unfortunately, Microsoft does not do a great job of documenting things like query string params that work in SharePoint. I don't even remember where I first picked it up (sometimes you see a native web part doing something & try it yourself) but I've been using successfully since SP2007. Here though is a blog post from 2012 that explains the same thing & offers a few more examples: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-search-filter-or-sort-lists.html

Comment: Hi @Stevangelista is there a documentation for this? I tried and it didn't work for me. By the way, I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010

Comment: I just found out it works for "Single line of text" columns but not for Lookup and Choice columns.

Comment: I've just tested & validated it works on the Status column (a Choice field) of an OOTB Task List in SP2007, SP2010 and SP2013. Are you sure you're applying it correctly? The query string param name itself is case-sensitive and you must use the internal column name of the column.

Comment: It works, although in my real case I'm using US cities and their state (Los Angeles, CA) and the "," is giving me problems. I had to wrap it with wildcards "*". Thanks! Any idea on how I can mix (FilterName & FilterMultiValue) with (FilterField & FilterValue)?

Comment: Glad it worked! And absolutely, check out the aforementioned link for an example that uses both in one URL.

Comment: Trying this - it works great with FilterField1/FilterValue1 but it ignores it when I use the same column name and same value in FilterName/FilterMultiValue. Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

On SPO, I tried FilterMultiValue and it did not work for me. But I've been successful with a simple operator **%3b%23** between values.

In this example URL, I am using view1 (a public view that already has some filtering in place), then filtering that view URL on the Product field for "value1" and "value2".

https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/library/Forms/view1.aspx?FilterFields1=Product&FilterValues1=value1%3b%value2&FilterTypes1=TaxonomyFieldType&viewid=2d0d02c1-4f0c-4eb8-9bea-4d7494bf7014

My use case: We have a product page with links to product documentation. Of course one product was easy. But I needed a lot of different links with different product combinations, and I didn't want to create or generate 1000 views.

To figure it out, I used the base URL for view1. Then I did onscreen filtering for the two values I wanted to see, which appends the URL. I used the appended URL to see that the "OR" operator is **%3b%23**. At that point, I used a spreadsheet with all the product values I needed for view URLs, and concatenated in the operator, creating a complete URL. Then we used those URLs in the web part for Product links. It's kind of a hack, but it is faster and easier to maintain than individual views or site pages.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue in Sharepoint 2013 (Office 365).  I created the exact filter I wanted within the List UI (multiple filters with one containing an AND clause for a single field), and then clicked "Save This View".  Worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for filtering multi value lookup column in SharePoint. Link for detailed instructions: [Multi value Lookup Columns in SharePoint](https://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/07/multi-value-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint.html)
Code for reference - Hope this helps some readers.

```js
function multiValueLookup() {
    var items = "";
    var citiesListName = "Cities";
    $("select[title='City possible values'] option").remove();
    $("select[title='State selected values'] option").each(function (i) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(citiesListName);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='State' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + $(this).val() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
        var items = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(items);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);
        function success() {
            var pn2 = "";
            var pn1 = "";
            var ListEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
                if (currentItem.get_item('Title') != null) {
                    var pn1 = currentItem.get_item('Title');
                    if (pn2 != pn1) {
                        items = "<option value='" + currentItem.get_item('ID') + "' title='" + pn1 + "'>" + pn1 + "</option>";
                        $("select[title='City possible values']").append(items);
                        pn2 = pn1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function failure(sender, args) {
            // alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining single-value and multi-value filters example which works for me:

```
&FilterFields1=Entity&FilterValues1=[value1]%3B%23[value2]&FilterField2=CustomContentType&FilterValue2=[value]
```

Single value fields &FilterField1=...&FilterValue1=...

Multi value fields (OR logic for the values) &FilterFields1=...&FilterValues1=...;#...

As per the example, the filter counter should always be incremented. encodeURIComponent(';#') = %3B%23 - this is the multi-value separator.

Done in SP2016; my Entity column is a choice one (multi-value).